# Number of solutions to these equations using algebraic ways

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

We have these equations over real numbers : $$ x^2 = 2^x $$ and $$ e^x = \ln x$$

First of all , we need number of solutions using algebraic ways and then find value of x individually in these equations .

Please Help!

Comment: What exactly does "using algebraic ways" mean?

Comment: I mean to use equations and functions.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom 'analytically'?

Comment: Yes , Exactly . My mean is 'analytically'.

Comment: These equations are not solvable with traditional algebraic techniques, unless you allow the use of the Lambert $W$ function.  In practice, these would be solved numerically.

Comment: For finding number of solutions , How we can use Lambert function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first equation, the real solutions are $x=2$, $x=4$ and $x = 
-\frac{2}{\ln(2)} W(\ln(2)/2)$, where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

Your second equation has no real solutions.

EDIT: The Lambert W solution comes about in the following way.
Write the equation as
$$ x^2 = e^{x \ln(2)} $$

Letting $x = - \dfrac{2 w}{\ln(2)}$, this becomes
$$ \dfrac{4 w^2}{\ln(2)^2} = e^{-2w} $$
i.e.
$$ w e^w = \pm \frac{\ln(2)}{2}$$

Now by definition the solutions of $w e^w = c$ are $w = W(c)$ where $W$ is a branch of the Lambert W function.  The real solutions are given by the "$0$" or principal branch if $c \ge -1/e$ and the "$-1$" branch if $-1/e \le c < 0$.

Now $-1/e < -\ln(2)/2 < 0$, so there we have both branches, but this happens to be one of the places where $W$ has "closed-form" values: $W_0( -\ln(2)/2) = -\ln(2)$ and $W_{-1}( -\ln(2)/2) = -2 \ln(2)$, corresponding to the equations
$$\eqalign{(-\ln(2)) e^{-\ln(2)} &= - \frac{\ln(2)}{2}\cr
            (-2 \ln(2)) e^{-2 \ln(2)} &= -\frac{\ln(2)}{2}\cr}$$
This is where the $x=2$ and $x=4$ solutions come from.

$+\ln(2)/2 > 0$, so here we have one real solution, $w = W_0(\ln(2)/2)$ (which  we write as just $W(\ln(2)/2)$), and so $x = \frac{-2}{\ln(2)} W(\ln(2)/2)$.

Comment: How you got it ? I need complete way and not try to guess solutions!

Comment: I don't think @Robert Israel deserves a very dry answer with a ? and a !. He has given you the three **exact** solutions. Usually, the third (non integer) root of this rather classical equation is given in an approximate manner, by a convergent sequence; see for instance (http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54607.html).

Comment: Duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/56325)

Comment: @JeanMarie Can you explain how we can find number of real roots using Lambert function ?

Comment: There is a single root that uses $W$ for its description. Its approximate value can be obtained through Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Yes! Wolfram Alpha is very good source but I can't use it in exams ! I want to find a way for counting number of solutions .

Comment: The point (whether you want to use $W$ or not to express the solutions) is that if $f(x) = x e^x$, $f(x) = y$ has no real solutions if $y < -1/e$, one (namely $x=-1$) if $y = -1/e$, two if $-1/e < y < 0$, and one if $y \ge 0$.  This can be seen from the properties of the graph of $f$.